# get the image from the api and how to set the dynamic height of each image in flutter?

Tags: flutter, image, containers, flutter-swiper

I get the image from the backend via the API, but flutter must set constraints in container, but the image height are not the same, what should I do?

Flutter image problems:

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_swiper/flutter_swiper.dart';
import 'package:flutter_use_redux/component/pureProduct.dart';
import 'package:flutter_use_redux/models/product.dart';
import 'package:flutter_use_redux/reselect/reselectHome.dart';
import 'package:oktoast/oktoast.dart';

/// 首页轮播组件编写
class SwiperDiy extends StatelessWidget {
  final List swiperDataList;
  final String imageHost;
  final bool autoPlay;

  SwiperDiy({Key key, this.swiperDataList,this.imageHost,this.autoPlay}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   Map swiperData= reselectSwiper(swiperDataList);
   List realSwiperData=swiperData['list'];
  
    return Container(
         constraints:
          BoxConstraints(
           maxHeight:550
         ),
        
        child:  Swiper(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        Map product=realSwiperData[index];
        return InkWell(
    onTap: () {
      print('/collections/${product['link']}');
    },
    child: CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl:imageHost+product['href'],fit: BoxFit.fill,),);
      },
      itemCount: realSwiperData?.length,
      //pagination: new SwiperPagination(),
      autoplay: realSwiperData.length>1,
      viewportFraction:1,
      // 当前视窗展示比例 小于1可见上一个和下一个视窗
      scale: 1,
    ),
      );
  }
}
```

This is my code. But the maxHeight is not suited for my thought:

[image]

For example, the image is from the network, sometimes its height maybe 300, sometimes its height maybe 400, I just want the swiper to stretch the Container.

Comment: Why are you using `BoxFit.fill`?

Comment: BoxFit.cover does not work ? so what should i do @Christopher Moore

Comment: Swiper is a collection of images right? So what do you expect to happen when you have different sized images in the collection? Either the larger images need to scale down to match the smallest image in swiper or the smaller images need to scale up to match the largest image.

Comment: some image is big ,some image is small,https://harbor.alpha.stylewe.com/ ,change the mobile mode, you can see the swiper carousel ,

Answer (score 0):

Use `height` and  `width` constructor of `Container`

```
 Container(
         height: 200,
         width: 200,
          //  constraints:
          //   BoxConstraints(
          //    maxHeight:550
          //  ),
          
       child:  Swiper(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          Map product=realSwiperData[index];
          return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
         print('/collections/${product['link']}');
      },
      child:  CachedNetworkImage(
            imageUrl:imageHost+product['href'],
           fit: BoxFit.fill,
           placeholder: (context, url) => Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
            errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Center(child: Icon(Icons.error)),
          )
     
      );
        },
        itemCount:  realSwiperData?.length,
        //pagination: new SwiperPagination(),
        autoplay: realSwiperData.length>1,,
        viewportFraction:1,
        // 当前视窗展示比例 小于1可见上一个和下一个视窗
        scale: 1,
      ),
        ),
```

Comment: but  the image from api ,it's height and width are variable， i just want to let the image strut it's parent , so the image could be bigger as it was

Comment: Then give it to the `height ` constructor of `Container `.

Comment: if container's height is 200,Swiper has no size , it throws error

Comment: Okay, I understood, what you wanna achieve, if I'm not getting  wrong you are trying to set the dynamic height of each image? Does that mean you are getting different height from the API for each image?

Comment: yes. the image is network image from the api,it's maybe 300 height, maybe 500 height,i want to let the image stretch the parent container web page